# Rails 3, how to update habtm relation with single check_box_tag or Confirm-/Refuse-Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many, update-attributes

I have a **habtm model** like:

```
class Recurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :include => :user
  has_many :users, :through => :participations 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations

  attr_accessible :scheduled_to, :user_id, :user_ids
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recurrence
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :recurrence_id, :user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :recurrences, :through => :participations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :phone, :recurrence_ids
end
```

with standard actions for the recurrences_controller (index, show, new, edit, create, update, destroy).

In the view of a single recurrence (/recurrences/10 -> show-action), I try to create/update the participation of user. When I do in the mentioned view something like:

```
<%= form_for @recurrence do |f| %>
  <div class="checkbox">  
      <% for user in User.find(:all) %>  
        <div>
          <%= check_box_tag "recurrence[user_ids][]", user.id, @recurrence.users.include?(user) %>  
          <%= user.name %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary'  %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

erverything is working fine, I can add or remove the participation for one or more users.

**BUT I like to do it - for just a single user**, namely the current_user! I tried with the following source:

```
<%= form_for(@recurrence) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag "recurrence[user_id]", current_user.id, 
      @recurrence.users.include?(current_user) %>
  <%= current_user.name %> 
  <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

which is **not working**, more detailed

- Updating the not changed status: not particpating, doesn't do anything: correct!
- Changing status: from not participating - to participating, works for current_user, BUT will also delete the status of a other users: wrong!
- Changing status: from participating - to not participating, won't change anything: wrong!

Any help is welcome!

Finaly I want to **reduce the Check-Box to Confirm-/Refuse-Buttons** with hidden-fields **for the recurrence**, but proabably there is easier rails-way?